Abbreviate street names using ArcGIS Pro field calculator?
I'm attempting to abbreviate these street names in this table and I'm unsure of exactly how the code should be written in python or arcade. Does anyone have any documentation on how this can be achieved using the field calculator? 

At least tell us what you'd like to see. -1

Sorry!
STREET - ST, AVENUE - AVE, ROAD - RD
I've been attempting to use !Street Name!. replace() with no luck, it will only replace the first value but I need to replace for multiple values

Yes it can be done in the field calculator, either python or Arcade should be able to do it. You will need an advanced field calculation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm quite far down the page; in python I would use a dictionary but that's a bit advanced, use multiple if statements evaluating Street_Name.split(' ')[-1] to get the last word, to put it all back together with ' '.join(Street_Name.split(' ')[:-1]) + ' abbreviation' (the leading space in the abbreviation is important).

There are a few ways to do it.  You could use a chain if replace() calls (eg, replace(" STREET", " ST").replace(" AVENUE", " AVE").replace(... etc.  But that's a bit ugly.  It would be nicer (and more maintainable!) to use a dictionary of replacements and run through each of them dynamically.  NB:  Notice the space character at the beginning of each string in my example?  Be sure to do that in case you have a road named, eg, "CRAVENUET STREET".

Simplest for you, select rows like '%STREET' and use !name![:-4]. Do similar thing with AVENUE etc

@SonofaBeach I wrote a script with a dictionary but it's failing due to syntax. I'm not sure what's wrong with it. If I were to use a chain of replace would that be done in the code block? Here's my code:
def update_streets(streets)
replacements = { 'STREET' : 'ST',
'AVENUE' : 'AVE'}
return (' '.join(streets.split(' ')[:-1]), replacements[streets.split()[-1}})

You're not accessing your dictionary properly, there shouldn't be curly bracers there, your return statement should read more like return ' '.join(streets.split(' ')[:-1]) + replacements[streets.split()[-1]], join only accepts one argument of type iterable (tuple, list, dictionary) and returns a string, you add the string sourced from the dictionary with the + operator. You have a bigger problem though, what happens when you encounter a road, terrace, lane - you will get a key error because the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. You will need to make a dict that has all the types in it.

No, a chain of replacements can all be done on one line in the expressions.  No need for a code block.  It's not a tidy solution, but it will work.

You need to edit the question and add your additional information to the question, NOT just in comments.  Some people will never read the comments, and even for those who do, it is easier to have all the relevant information in one place in an organised fashion within the question.  You need to make it easy for people to help you.

@SonofaBeach I would be cautious of using replace statements, they can go a little wild, for example 'STREETS ICE CREAM ROAD' would become 'S ICE CREAM RD'. Been there, done that and cleaned up the mess afterward.

@Michael_Stimson, yes I agree.  I've included a leading space in each of my strings which would take care of most of those cases.  However, for multi-word street names where the non-first word is a problem candidate, it's still an issue.

This is not the most sophisticated or efficient solution, but it easy to implement.  It's also not terribly easy to read or maintain, but it is simple to write.
Chain a replace() call for each replacment you want to use.  replace() returns a string, so you can just run replace() on that again, as many times as you want.
Expression:
!street_name!.replace(" STREET", " ST").replace(" AVENUE", " AVE").replace(" LANE", " LN")

NB:  Note that each of these strings includes a leading space.  This will prevent it from affecting the first word in the streetname where that word includes the same letter combination as one of your street types.
You will need to add other replacements to the end of this, of course, if you have any others (eg, .replace(" COURT", " CT", etc).
NB:  This will NOT work correctly for cases where the street name has more than two words and a non-first and non-last word includes one of your street types.  Eg, "MAXIMILLION CRAVENUET STREET" would become "MAXIMILLION CRAVET ST" (because "CRAVENUET" conatins "AVENUE".  So you would need to be certain that none of your street names would be affected by this caveat.

A solution that is more robust (less prone to various errors) and more maintainable (eg, easier to view and add/remove abbreviations) but more complex to write than the replace() chaining could be like this:
EXPRESSION:
streetAbbr(!Street_Name!)

CODE BLOCK:
abbreviations = {
    "STREET": "ST",
    "AVENUE": "AVE",
}

def streetAbbr(street):
    global abbreviations
    if street is None:
        return None
    nameParts = street.split(" ")
    if len(nameParts):
        for longName in abbreviations:
            if nameParts[-1].upper() == longName.upper():
                nameParts[-1] = abbreviations[longName]
                return " ".join(nameParts)
    return street

Again, you may want to add more rows to the abbreviations dictionary, such as, "LANE": "LN",, and any others that could be in your data.
Here's what the code block does:

Defines the dictionary of values OUTSIDE of the function, so that it only needs to be defined once (instead of every time the function is called for every feature/record)
Defines the function that does all the work
Includes the global dictionary for use within the function
Checks for NULL value and returns None (NULL) if the value is NULL (otherwise the rest of the function will fail for NULL values)
Splits the name into parts (separated by space character)
Checks to see if there actually are any parts (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to run on an empty string)
Iterates through each of the items in the dictionary
Checks the last element of the name parts for a match with the current dictionary item (case insensitive!)
if it matches, it replaces the last name part with the corresponding value from the dictionary and then returns a string with all of the name parts joined together with spaces in between (and of course will not continue looping through any remaining items in the dictionary)
in the case that nothing gets returned within the loop, it will then return the original value passed in

As you can see, what may seem like a very simple task, is a lot more complicated than it first appears (at least if you want to do it well).

Nice, that will also catch unusual names like 'Some Road E' and any abbreviation that's not in the dictionary simply won't change instead of raising a key error. +1

Another option. Use a dictionary with List Comprehension.
Replace CompleteSt with the name of your existing street name field, and adjust the d dictionary:
abbr(!CompleteSt!)

def abbr(street):
    d = {"Road":"Rd",
         "Lane":"Ln",
         "Drive":"Drv",
         "Street":"St"
         "Avenue":"Av"}
    street_list = street.split(" ") #Split the street name at each whitespace into a list
    new_name_list = [d[x] if x in d else x for x in street_list] #For each word, replace those that exist in the dictionary
    new_street_name = ' '.join(new_name_list) #Join the list into a string
    return new_street_name

.

